# Understanding Multibyte/Unicode

Tags: c++, unicode, macros, mfc

I'm just getting back into Programming C++, MFC, Unicode.  Lots have changed over the past 20 years.

Code on another project compiled just fine, but had errors when I paste it into my code.  It took me 1-1/2 days of wasted time to solve the function call below:

```
enter code here
CString CFileOperation::ChangeFileName(CString sFileName)
{
  char drive[MAX_PATH], dir[MAX_PATH], name[MAX_PATH], ext[MAX_PATH];
  _splitpath_s(sFileName, drive, dir, name, ext);  //error
  ------- other code
}
```

After reading help, I changed the CString sFileName to use a cast:

```
enter code here
_splitpath_s((LPTCSTR)sFileName, drive, dir, name, ext);  //error
```

This created an error too.  So then I used GetBuffer() which is really the same as above.

```
enter code here
char* s = sFileName.GetBuffer(300);
_splitpath_s(s, drive, dir, name, ext);  //same error for the 3rd time
sFileName.ReleaseBuffer();
```

At this point I was pretty upset, but finally realized that I needed to change the CString to Ascii (I think because I'm set up as Unicode).

hence;

```
enter code here
CT2A strAscii(sFileName);   //convert CString to ascii, for splitpath()
```

then use strAscii.m_pz in the function _splitpath_s()

This finally worked.  So after all this, to make a  story short, I need help focusing on:
1.   Unicode vs Mulit-Byte (library calls)
2.   Variables to uses

I'm willing to purchase another book, please recommend.
Also, is there a way to filter my help on VS2015 so that when I'm on a variable and press F1, it only gives me help for Unicode and ways to convert old code to unicode or convert Mylti-Byte to Unicode.

Hope this is not to confusing, but I have some catching up to do.  Be patient if my verbiage is not perfect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please re-read http://stackoverflow.com/tour... SO is for concrete programming questions and any sort of recommendations are off-topic here. As side note: picking some other language (i.e. C# as you are using VS already) or at least more modern library for C++ would make finding help much easier...

Comment: _Lots have changed over the past 20 years._ .. yup, more esoteric ways to incur buffer overflows :)

Comment: Start here: http://www.unicode.org/standard/principles.html  Pay attention to "code points" and the UTF-X ways of encoding them into multibytes.

Comment: As an aside, `GetBuffer()` is the wrong member function, if all you need is a pointer to the non-mutable buffer of a string object. You should use [CString::GetString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sddk80xf.aspx#csimplestringt__getstring) instead.

Comment: Thanks; I did not know GetString() existed (as it did not back then).  I've read some about it and see that it was implemented in

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation of `_splitpath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e737s6tf.aspx) lists a Unicode (`wchar_t` based) version `_wsplitpath`. That's the one you should be using. Don't convert to ASCII or Windows ANSI, that will in general lose information and not produce a valid path when you recombine the pieces.

Modern Windows programming is Unicode based.

A Visual Studio C++ project is Unicode-based by default, in particular it defines the macro symbol `UNICODE`, which affects the declarations from `<windows.h>`.

Comment: A Unicode-based project also defines the `_UNICODE` preprocessor symbol that controls the generic-text mappings of the CRT. Neither the `UNICODE` nor the `_UNICODE` symbol are necessary, though, if you invoke explicit Unicode-versions of function calls (as you recommend in this answer).

Comment: Uhm, I'm not recommending to generally use the `...W` forms of API functions explicitly. As I see it the code gets much more readable without those. E.g. I just write `MessageBox`, not `MessageBoxW`. But I'm not familiar with any prefix-free form of `_wsplitpath`. Wrt. the runtime library's `_UNICODE`, it's worth noting that the CRT stuff differentiates between [three encodings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z097dxa.aspx), not just two as `<windows.h>` does: for the CRT there's also  `_MBCS`, if I recall correctly. Defining both `_MBCS` and `_UNICODE` would be an error.

Comment: Pretty inconsistent recommendation to use `_wsplitpath` (vs. `_tsplitpath`), but `MessageBox` (vs. `MessageBoxW`). There's no readily conceivable rationale to advice against using `TCHAR`s (which is fine), but keep using the generic-text mappings for *only* Windows API calls.

Comment: @IInspectable: The old purpose (generic text mapping) doesn't matter for using the simple documented API function names. The extraordinary number of macros is an annoyance and plays havoc even with Microsoft's own code, in some cases. But one can't avoid that anyway: there's no way to tell `<windows.h>` to not define the macros. If there were, then I'd be inclined to think twice or more about disagreeing with you here. ;-)

Comment: *"The extraordinary number of macros is an annoyance"* - And that's why you propose to keep using them? For no comprehensible benefit? *"But one can't avoid that anyway: there's no way to tell `<windows.h>` to not define the macros."* - But there is `#undef`, so you can have macro-free code, if you care enough. Well, not you, of course, because you decided to write code that relies on them annoying macros. Incidentally, why?

Comment: There are many hundreds of these <windows.h> macros. I think the number is in excess of 1200, I'm not sure.

Comment: Simple counting in g++'s version of `<windows.h>`, without lean n' mean defined, which as I recall roughly halves the number, I got 24 421 macros. Most of them are not function macros. But that's too many to `#undef`.

Comment: *"But that's too many to `#undef`."* - If someone ships header files that `#define` *n* macros, I don't see why it should be impossible for someone to ship a header file that `#undef`s *n* macros. But that is all besides the point. You are weaseling around answering the real question: Why do you propose to be explicit everywhere, but use the generic-text mapping macros for Windows API calls?

Comment: The cost (macros) can't be avoided in practice. And adding the `W` does nothing but add verbosity: it lowers the readability and thus the clarity of the code. And it's in direct conflict with the DRY principle: Don't Repeat Yourself, especially not ad nauseam. Thus it would just be dumb to not avail oneself of using the more readable names, so, I don't recommend abstaining from use of readable names, and I apologize for using so vague wording that one could interpret it that way.

Comment: PS: A more refined count of function macros in g++'s `<windows.h>` now gave me 779, more in line with the number 1200 that I remembered. I haven't checked Visual C++'s version. Essentially I now counted only those macro definitions that contained `W(`, which as it happened picked those that contained `__MINGW_NAME_AW(`.

Comment: That's hardly convincing. I don't see how a trailing character, with *clear and documented* semantics were to add verbosity. And what about situations, where you cannot even use the macro? You haven't made a convincing point to justify using macros and do so inconsistently, too. I'd hope you would edit your answer so I can un-upvote it, because clearly I have misinterpreted your proposition.

Answer (score 1):

All supported versions of Windows use Unicode internally throughout, and your application should, too. Windows uses [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) encoding.

To make your application Unicode-enabled you need to perform the following steps:

- Set up your project's [Character Set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x480de8.aspx) to *"Use Unicode Character Set"* (if it's currently set to *"Use Multi-Byte Character Set"*). This is not strictly required, but it deals with those cases, where you aren't using the Unicode version explicitly.
- Use `wchar_t` (in place of `char` or `TCHAR`) for your strings.
- Use wide character string literals (`L"..."` in place of `"..."`).
- Use `CStringW` (in place of `CStringA` or `CString`) in an MFC project.
- Explicitly call the Unicode version of the CRT (e.g. `wcslen` in place of `strlen` or `_tcslen`).
- Explicitly call the Unicode version of any Windows API call where it exists (e.g. `CreateWindowExW` in place of `CreateWindowExA` or `CreateWindowEx`).

Comment: Adding those `W` suffixes just makes the code less readable. It's like Microsoft's [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Disadvantages). Just needless, negative value verbosity. So that's bad advice. The rest is mostly good. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Those that blindly critique Hungarian notation usually haven't grasped it. I invite you to download and have a look at the source code for [Microsoft Word 1.1a](http://www.computerhistory.org/atchm/microsoft-word-for-windows-1-1a-source-code/). Also, from your (opinionated) link: *"Most arguments against Hungarian notation are against *Systems* Hungarian notation, not *Apps* Hungarian notation."*

Answer (score 0):

Try using `_tsplitpath_s` and `TCHAR`.

So the final code looks something like:

```
CString CFileOperation::ChangeFileName(CString sFileName)
{
  TCHAR drive[MAX_PATH], dir[MAX_PATH], name[MAX_PATH], ext[MAX_PATH];
  _tsplitpath_s(sFileName, drive, dir, name, ext);  //error
  ------- other code
}
```

This will enable C++ compiler to use the correct character width during build time depending on the project settings

Comment: The Windows 9x compatibility macros are 20 years past the "use before" date. As I see it it's worse than meaningless to try to support a Windows version that your compiler can't generate an executable for.